# Modal pop up has stopped functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

A third party developer created a modal popup for our meet the team page. It has stopped working for some reason.

By clicking the staff members picture their details should appear below the image

the page is: https://www.bennettsfunerals.co.uk/about-bennetts-funeral-directors-essex/meet-the-team/

I have pasted below what i think is the function script.

Why would this suddenly stop working!!!???

==============================================

$('.team').click(function() {

```
            var _this = $(this);

            if( $(_this).hasClass('active') )

            {

                return false;

            }

            else

            {

                $('.team.active').removeClass('active');

                $(_this).addClass('active');

                $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay"></div>');
            }
        });

        $(window).on('click', '.overlay', function(e) {

            $('.team.active').removeClass('active');

            $('.overlay').remove();

        });



        $('.close-overlay').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $('.team.active').removeClass('active');

            $('.overlay').remove();

            return false;
        });

        $('.print').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            window.print();
        });
    });




        $('.close-overlay').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $('.team.active').removeClass('active');

            $('.overlay').remove();

            return false;
        });

        $('.print').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            window.print();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the developer console you will see that there is a Syntax Error at line 1048 of your index document. That error is caused because there is a curly bracket missing:

```
$('#responsive-sidebar-button').click(function() // need a curly bracket here

    if($('.sidebar').hasClass('opened')) {

        $('.sidebar').removeClass('opened');

        $('.sidebar').slideUp();

    } else {

        $('.sidebar').addClass('opened');

        $('.sidebar').slideDown();

    }

});
```

So you'll end up with this:

```
$('#responsive-sidebar-button').click(function(){

    if($('.sidebar').hasClass('opened')) {

        $('.sidebar').removeClass('opened');

        $('.sidebar').slideUp();

    } else {

        $('.sidebar').addClass('opened');

        $('.sidebar').slideDown();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Code gets broken due to syntax error(**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if**). **Curly brace({)** is missing at line 1046 of your index file.

Line : 1046

```
$('#responsive-sidebar-button').click(function() //function curly brace is missed

    $('#responsive-sidebar-button').click(function() { //Need to add this curly brace here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine as it is. If you copy the following code and run in the console, your desired output works. Since there is an issue of missing `{` brace, the click event listeners won't get registered on the `img`. So it didn't work.

```
$('.team').click(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    if( $(_this).hasClass('active') )
    {
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       $('.team.active').removeClass('active');
       $(_this).addClass('active');
       $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    }});
$('.close-overlay').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.team.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.overlay').remove();
    return false;
});
```